# Change input values from an object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have multiple color inputs that are being displayed with unique colors. They are getting their value from a helper which is a nested Object. When I attempt to update the value, nothing occurs. I logged out the state and saw that all the colors are still an object. I attempted to get the individual color values and use that as the initial state with `Object.values()`, but there was no success in that.

As a test, I created a new input and state that held a random hex value and it updated without any issue. I'm assuming since I'm still getting back an object in my `colorVal` state, that I need to somehow get the values of the color object and convert it into a string?

I'm a bit lost and have been working on this for days now.

[image: screenshot]

**Component to display inputs**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ColorPicker from './ColorPicker';

import { colorSelect, colorNames, colors } from '../Theme/colorSections'
import styled from 'styled-components';

function ColorPickerSection() {
  const [colorVal, setColorVal] = useState(colors)

   const onColorChange = (e) => {
    setColorVal(e.target.value)
  }

  console.log(colorVal);

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(colorSelect).map(groupName => {
        return (<div>
          <GroupName>{groupName}</GroupName>
          {Object.keys(colorSelect[groupName]).map(color => {
            return (
              <ColorPicker
                key={color}
                label={color}
                value={colorVal[color]}
                onChange={onColorChange}
              />
            )
          })}
        </div>)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Individual Color Swatch Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'

function ColorPicker(props) {
  return (
    <ColorPickerContainer>
      <p>{props.label}</p>
      <ColorSwatch type="color" value={props.value} onChange={props.onColorChange} />
      <HexInput
        type="text"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onColorChange}
      />
    </ColorPickerContainer>
  );
}
```

**Color Helper**

```
const colorSelect = {
  'Line Highlights': {
    highlightBackground: '#F7EBC6',
    highlightAccent: '#F7D87C'
  },
  'Inline Code': {
    inlineCodeColor: '#DB4C69',
    inlineCodeBackground: '#F9F2F4'
  },
  'Code Blocks': {
    blockBackground: '#F8F5EC',
    baseColor: '#5C6E74',
    selectedColor: '#b3d4fc'
  },
  'Tokens': {
    commentColor: '#93A1A1',
    punctuationColor: '#999999',
    propertyColor: '#990055',
    selectorColor: '#669900',
    operatorColor: '#a67f59',
    operatorBg: '#FFFFFF',
    variableColor: '#ee9900',
    functionColor: '#DD4A68',
    keywordColor: '#0077aa'
  }
}

const colorNames = []
const colors = {}

Object.keys(colorSelect).map(key => {
  const group = colorSelect[key]
  Object.keys(group).map(color => {
    colorNames.push(color)
    colors[color] = group[color]
  })
})

export { colorSelect, colorNames, colors }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming e.target.value is indeed the new color code in string.
The 'colors' is an object to begin with, so when you get the new color code, you need to update the object property accordingly

```js
const onColorChange = (e, colorValKey) => {
    setColorVal({
      ...colors,
      [colorValKey]: e.target.value
    })
}

return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(colorSelect).map(groupName => {
        return (<div>
          <GroupName>{groupName}</GroupName>
          {Object.keys(colorSelect[groupName]).map(color => {
            return (
              <ColorPicker
                key={color}
                label={color}
                value={colorVal[color]}
                onChange={(e) => onColorChange(e, color)}
              />
            )
          })}
        </div>)
      })}
    </div>
  )
```

Edit

```js
// We passed onChange={onColorChange}, so props.onColorChange is undefined
<HexInput 
  type="text" 
  value={props.value} 
  onChange={props.onColorChange} />


// Should be
<HexInput 
  type="text" 
  value={props.value} 
  onChange={props.onChange} />
```